What kind of cactus did I buy?
Loving a new cactus we just got and would like to learn more about it. How can I include a photo here?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi Vince, and welcome to the site.  Here are instructions on how to add a photo to your post: https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/798/how-to-post-images-here/992#992
